# Spring Boot application initialization problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, gradle

I have 2 spring boot applications A and B managed by Gradle. B was packaged as a normal jar and imported as a dependency in A. And B's main() function/entry point will be called by A based on the business logic.

The problem right now is that when I was trying to start A, B's initialization stage somehow took over the control and overwrote the start process of A.

Is there any way to customize the initialization order or invoke B only when I need it?

**Update:**
[image]

The Application class that being extended is the entry point of B, and main() is invoked inside the function.
The application is supposed to accept arguments from the command line, then parse them and pass them to this scanHelper().

[image]
The output shows it invokes B's main() directly, so it's not able to recognize the arguments.

Here is the B's jar structure
[image]

Comment: `B's initialization stage somehow took over the control and overwrote the start process of A`, but the class that contains the main() has a unique FQN ? Maybe post your Spring output ... Both projects share the same namespace ?

Comment: @PeterMmm Hi peter, thanks for commenting, I've updated the post

Comment: Why DetectScanHelper extends Application ?

Comment: @PeterMmm cause the Application class is the entry point of B. The only way to run B is to call the main() in the Application class.